# Removing all missing downloads from the completed list

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I use `µTorrent` as my torrent client. Consider I have downloaded torrent and they are completed. Then I moved the completed file or deleted.
Earlier there used to be an option where it used to show them as missing `red` in status bar but now even when the file is not there it still shows them `Finished`.

How can I remove all those downloads from the list which I have deleted and don't exists anymore? The list is long so doing one by one is not really an ideal options. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

> but now even when the file is not there it still shows them `Finished`.

Select all torrents <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, then stop and start the torrent(s) again and they will become red.

Sort by status and delete.

Comment: It worked till some extent deleted the torrent from the list but added them to `queued` downloads again

Comment: @Maven did you set uTorrent to load `.torrent` files from a folder?

Answer (score 0):

In `µTorrent` you can select more the one torrent at the time with the  <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> keys. Exactly like in `Explorer`.